# Django create view template breadcrumbs based on url dynamically

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a link :

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/modules/list/?page=1
```

How do I create a breadcrumbs based on the url above just like below:

```
Home > modules > list
```

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple. Override `{% block breadcrumbs %}` (base.html)